# iOS UIWebview get edit event?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I have an editable webview in my view controller. When the view controller gets loaded the webview will also get loaded with some html data.

Along with that i would like to add some more content. Once I have done it. i want to resize the webview to show the whole content of it in the view controller without scrolling..

So, Is there any way to get the event once the editing is done on UIWebview??

Really struck with this for last two weeks.

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you got any solution for it?

Comment: the only thing which helped me is : i have done by getting the keyboard event and view focus.. but its not the actual way to do it..